# Regex match line above (Perl)

Tags: regex, perl, cisco

I want to write a simple script which gives me from a Cisco Configuration every Port which is not in use (shutdown). The shutdown Ports looks always the same like:

```
interface Ethernet100/1/40
  shutdown
```

Which Regex can I use to get always the line above 'shutdown' ?
I want to write this script in Perl, please help me.

Comment: `grep -B1 'shutdown' file | awk NR==1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn multiline option on and use this:

```
^.+$(?=\s+shutdown)
```

That will match the line before the word `shutdown`.

It's basically looking for a line of any characters `^.+$`, looking ahead for some whitespace followed by `shutdown`.

Try it here: https://regex101.com/r/WFqX5A/1

Answer (score 0):

You can match also all after "interface" by adding few letters to above

```
^interface\s\K.*$(?=\s+shutdown)
```